# Stopping Multiple Services Windows 7 using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

During my internet searches, I have found a script that is supposed to stop a service. The current script runs, finds the services specified in an array, but doesn't seem to stop them. When the script outputs the services' `State`, it's still running. Below is the script.

```
sComputer = "."
aTargetSvcs= Array("mysql","Apache2.4")

Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!\\" _
 & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set cServices = oWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service")

For Each oService In cServices
 For Each sTargetSvc In aTargetSvcs
  If LCase(oService.Name) = LCase(sTargetSvc) Then

   If oService.State <> "Stopped" Then
    oService.StopService()
    Wscript.Echo oService.State
   End If 

  End If  
 Next
Next
```

I am just testing it out with `mysql` and `Apache2.4` services, but when this works, it will be deployed with a group policy to temporarily stop some AV services that are interfering with a domain modifier script.

Comment: Not the most elegant script I've seen for this sort of thing. It's likely a permission problem, you probably don't have the rights to stop the services in the context the script is run.

Comment: That was it. I ran it with Administrative Privileges in the command line, and it has stopped the services. Did you want to put that as an answer so I can select it as being correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely a lack of permission in the context of the running script.

If you run the script from the command line make sure to start it through an Elevated Command Prompt, in modern Windows Operating Systems an elevated Command Prompt is denoted by the prefix `Administrator:` in the Window Title.

If you run the script from a Shortcut link make sure to specify `Run As Administrator` in the `Advanced Properties` screen.